# Does VS Code have anything like Atom's addKeystrokeResolver?

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor, vscode-extensions

Atom has a feature that allows you to intercept keyboard input events and transform them into different keyboard input before Atom does anything with them. Here's an example from Atom's documentation:

```
atom.keymaps.addKeystrokeResolver ({event}) ->
  if event.code is 'KeyG' and event.altKey and event.ctrlKey and event.type isnt 'keyup'
    return 'ctrl-@'
```

This code causes Atom to treat ctrl-alt-g as if it were ctrl-@.

(See http://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/#overriding-atoms-keyboard-layout-recognition)

Does VS Code have anything similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what the VSCode vim extension does: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/aa8d9549ac0d31b393a9346788f9a9a93187c222/extension.ts#L208

It hooks into and overrides VSCode's `type` command. This is a lower level extension point than atom's keystroke resolvers but it may provide what you are looking for